# Android MainActivity.java Error (works on tablet but not on phone)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intellij-idea, adt

I've been writing this application for my project and I've come through a strange situtation and need help since I cannot find the mistake and there are no errors when compiling. Also, the application works on my Nexus 7 (2013) tablet with Kitkat 4.4.2 and it doesn't work on my Samsung Galaxy S2 with Cyanogenmod 11 M6 installed. Also, it doesn't work on a Galaxy S4 with stock rom running Android 4.4.2. I'm getting the error on Line 16 of the MainActiviy.java file when I check the errors on logcat. You can find the logcat logs, MainActivity.java file, activity_main.xml file and the android manifest below. I'm using Intellij Idea but get the similar results on Android Developer Tools. Thank you very much.

MainActivity.java:

```
package gpec.app.metudexter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageButton online_Button, mail_Button, apu_Button, sca_Button, lib_Button, ratingButton; //curriculum_Button,

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //ERROR HAPPENS HERE

    online_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.onlineButton);
    online_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Online.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    apu_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apuButton);
    apu_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Apu.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    mail_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mailButton);
    mail_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mail.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

/*  curriculum_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.curriculumButton);
    curriculum_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Curriculum.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    }); */

    sca_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.scaButton);
    sca_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sca.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    lib_Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.libButton);
    lib_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Library.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

    ratingButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ratingButton);
    ratingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Library.class);
            // myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

My Android Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="gpec.app.metudexter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="gpec.app.metudexter.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="locked"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Chat"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Online"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Mail"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Apu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="Table"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="Curriculum"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Sca"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Library"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Calculus"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="Rating"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

Logcat:

```
06-01 20:34:41.594    7177-7177/gpec.app.metudexter E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to inflate
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2170)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 20:34:41.599    7177-7177/gpec.app.metudexter D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-01 20:34:41.599    7177-7177/gpec.app.metudexter W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4178fce0)
06-01 20:34:41.609    7177-7177/gpec.app.metudexter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: gpec.app.metudexter, PID: 7177
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gpec.app.metudexter/gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2170)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at gpec.app.metudexter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/apuButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/apu"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/onlineButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/lms"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mailButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/mail"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/scaButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/sca"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/libButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/library"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/rating"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: copy the activity_main layout here. The problem is with the layout file. and tell us how you're organizing your layout? I mean what's the folder structure for the layouts ?

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi I've added activity_main.xml file. Thanks

Comment: They are all in the layout folder in res folder

Comment: I think the problem might be the layout_weight on linearlayouts, since the parent one doesn't have a weightSum value and its 3 child linearlayouts have weight=1 and layout_height=0dp , for their own. try to tweak this one first. Secondly, try to remove weight from the child linearlayouts and organize your components using another workaround, such as relativelayout

Comment: I'm trying to do your suggestions. Let's see if I can make it :)

Comment: Following your stacktrace, the `OutOfMemoryError` gets thrown when loading your drawables, so I don't understand why people try to redesign your layout here. Look at other StackOverflow threads that deal with `OutOfMemoryError` while loading bitmaps from drawable resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Voicu's comment, I've checked some web pages on the web and I found out that the problem was the number of image buttons that I'm using and their size. After resizing the image buttons for different screen resolutions, problem got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a problem with setContentView, it's most probably an XML error within your **layout file**, although it may be dependant on whether you have a seperate layout in a folder for tablet screens, e.g. layout-sw600dp.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, I don't have an xml file for bigger screens. I've added my activity_main.xml file to the post.

Comment: It seems you have nested weights (bad for performance) - the ImageButtons and their parent LinearLayout have the layout_weight. Remove layout_weight for the ImageButtons and it may fix it, but I doubt it.

Comment: Also, try to use relative layouts instead on multiple LinearLayouts with nested weights.

Comment: Relative Layout doesnt work. I've tried it before and it messed up the whole thing.

Comment: Also, for the first suggestion; it cleared out the buttons in the first place. However, I tried to use wrap content for android:layout_width for the buttons and I got 1x3 button layout instead of 2x3. It just streched one of the buttons at each row

Comment: A GridLayout/TableLayout/GridView could also work, but their implementations are far more complex.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've tried them before but couldn't success. I'm trying to add make the main layout as relative and playing with the linear layouts' weights and positions and other stuff. Let's see if this will help :)